# How do I add bevel after boolean and still have a clean shading

Tags: modifiers, bevel

I used the Decimate modifier "trick" before Bevel modifer without Clamp Overlap. But I am still not able to get a clean shading. I have adjusted everything and used Auto Smooth and Weighted Normals. Can someone tell me a free way to do this everytime? Thanks.
.
.
[image]

Comment: please show a screenshot of your mesh in edit mode. the decimate modifier will mess up your topology. and with bad topology your bevel modifiers will fail.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I am sorry. I got frustrated and closed the project without saving. The model lives no more.

Comment: ok. well, you could just delete this question thread :)

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie But I still need the answer no? I come across this shading problem in many models where Boolean is used.

Comment: yes because booleans are evil. they usually destroy the topology. so whenever you use booleans you usually have to manually fix your topology.

Comment: In the addon, i think HardOps, there is a feature that eats through any geometry when you Bevel an edge, any edge. I wish someone can teach me how to do that using Modifiers because it is possible, albeit complicated.

Comment: @NewBlenderer HardOps also just uses things like sharpening edges, bevel modifier, smooth shading etc., it's not a magic trick. If there is really bad topology there can be parts looking messy with HardOps as well (I have HardOps myself).

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I see. I have followed many tutorials of Josh Grambell and others who heavily use HardOps. It did seem like magic though eating away from edges to make a clean bevel (in experimental feature set). I wanted to know the sequence of modifiers that it uses to make a clean bevel. If it's answerable.

Comment: @NewBlenderer But there are also tutorials by Josh where he's showing how to manually clean up areas that don't work so well.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Umm.... YOLO